# Applying law of the unconscious statistician (LOTUS) to wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-information, quantum-optics, statistics

I have a wavefunction $\psi(x)$ given by the points-spread function of a spatial invariant aperture. I define the wavefunction of an arbitrary photon incident on the aperture as $\psi_s(x) = \psi(x-x_s+\xi)$ where $x_s$ is the position of the photons source relative to the center axis and $\xi$ is some fixed offset. Now if I have $k$ sources of relative brightness's $\epsilon_s$ ($\sum\limits_{s=0}^k\epsilon_s = 1$). Measuring the position of the photon density I get back the image plane distribution given by:
$$\begin{aligned}
\Lambda(x,\xi) &= \langle x |\left(\sum\limits_{s=0}^k\epsilon_s| \psi_s\rangle \langle \psi_s | \right)|x\rangle\\
&= \sum\limits_{s=0}^k\epsilon_k|\psi_s(x)|^2
\end{aligned}
$$

Now if the fixed offset is drawn from the random variable $\Xi \sim \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ my point-spread function for each source becomes $\psi_s(x) = \psi(x-x_s+\Xi)$. To find the probabilities I apply [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) to the image plane distribtion $\Lambda(x)$

$$
\Lambda(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F_\Xi(\xi)\Lambda(x,\xi)d\xi
$$

However, in my mind I should be able to apply LOTUS to each of the wave-functions $\psi_s(x)$ before measuring the position of the photon density and get the same result. In practice however I am getting very different results and I am struggling to understand whether it is more appropriate to apply LOTUS initially or later .

Comment: What is a "spatial invariant aperture"?

Comment: @flippiefanus LOTUS is [Law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician). And spatially invariant means that is the point spread function was Gaussian than a photon at $x_0$ would just be drawn from a Gaussian PDF with mean $x_0$ where a photon incident at $x_1$ would just have a mean of $x_1$. Basically to say the PSF is not a function of the incident position $x_s$ you can just substitute $x = x-x_s$.

Comment: OK, but you are talking about an aperture and an aperture is never shift invariant.

Comment: What I mean to say is magnification of the image system is spatially invariant. As in I assume the system has unit magnification and a photon incident on the aperture has a PSF on the image plane as $\psi(x-x_s)$ the PSF at the centre of the imaging plane shifted by $x_s$.